# Why Encoder is not in the package kafka.serializer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'm trying to encode an object of class to send using kafka producer
The class has many attributes :

```
public class CarData implements Serializable{
    private String vehicleId;
    private String lon;
    private String lat;
}
```

I want to encode and send an object of CarData

```
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, CarData>(topicName, car_data));
```

But the error appears like below image

[[package kafka.serializer doesn't contain Encoder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V6En.png)]

Answer (score 2):

Because it was deprecated, then removed, and you should be importing some serializer class within `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization` or write your own Serializer

Note: using Java serializable isn't very efficient and definitely not cross-language compatible.

Comment: This is weird, why there is Decoder but no Encoder?
What is the purpose of the Decoder in this case?

Comment: I believe both should be deprecated. Serializer and Deserializer are the new implementations

Comment: Also, you should remove that kafka_2.11 JAR, and only use `kafka-clients`